# Install Delphi XE5 Android emulator not recognized

Tags: delphi

I'm new to Delphi XE 5 and currently building my first multi platform firemonkey application. I would like to run my program on a mobile device, for testing first I need the emulator.  I installed the emulator from the Embarcadero app wave store, build id = 5554

In my Delphi program manger window I see this emulator <5554>  is available as a target (ZIEl) but I can not activate this target. Furthermore I can not use this device during program development as a testing device.

How to get this emulator running for my program ?

[image: see screen dump for more details]

As shown in the tutorial video I also did find the USB debugging option on the emulator

Comment: Is the documentation of any help? [`Android Mobile Application Development`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development) and [`Creating an Android Emulator`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator).

Comment: Don't use the appwave emulator.  Did you read anything about the AppWave store? It's a special "app sandbox/streaming/virtualization" system.  You're running an emulator inside a sandbox now. The regular non-appwave XE5 installer already INSTALLS THE ANDROID EMULATOR FOR YOU.  Or are you also running XE5 inside AppWave?  That's also gonna be a problem if you want to use AppWave for Android development as I doubt they put the Android Emulator inside the AppWave package.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this link:

Creating an Android Emulator:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_Emulator

Before you create an Android emulator, you need to install an Android system image that your emulators can use.